# Pandoc: use syntax highlighting in HTML without creating anchors?

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, pandoc

I just noticed that when Pandoc creates syntax highlighting, it also creates an HTML anchor for each code line:

[image]

This results in a lot of invisible tab stops. Is there a way to suppress creating those anchors?

Answer (score 1):

There is no switch to stop the anchors from being generated, but it is possible to disable them via CSS:

```css
pre > code.sourceCode a {
  display: none;
}
```

This will hide all line anchors, and the tab stops will be gone.

Comment: This is a very useful idea. Thank you, I will do it like that.